# Cannot Install MicroPython For Pico on Thonny

Tags: micropython

I am trying to install MicroPython on the Thonny editor on Linux but I cannot get it to work. If I hover over "tools" it shows "Install MicroPython to ESP8266/ESP32 ..." and under it, "Erase ESP8266/ESP32 flash" but they are both greyed out and don't do anything if they are selected. My pi is plugged in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.